# Chi-squared statistic applied on bacterial areas

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, chi-squared-test, model

I read a [tutorial](http://www.rpgroup.caltech.edu/ncbs_pboc/code/t1b_ecoli_growth.html) on how to estimate the growth rate of E.coli by 1) assuming the growth is exponential, 2) computing the area using image processing techniques and 3) comparing the areas computed in these two different ways and doing some curve fitting.

Now, I was modeling a cell population and came up with a different area formula, namely:

$$A(t)=A_{\text{initial}} 2^{t/a_d},$$

where $a_d$ is the age at which the cells divide (in minutes). I want to follow the same procedure as in the tutorial, in order to estimate the age of division instead of the growth rate. I just replaced the formula. However, the graph of $\chi^2$ is always a curve that decreases, and the minimum is always the upper bound of the age range that I set, whichever that is. Not to mention that the curve fitting is completely messed up.

What am I doing wrong and how could I apply my formula to this method?

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, per this source on the ['Definition of Exponential Growth'](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/exponential-growth.html),
to quote:

> Where a value increases in proportion to its current value. Such as always doubling.
>
> The general formula is:
>
> $y(x) = ab^{kx}$
>
> Notice the variable "x" on the right hand side is part of the exponent (hence "exponential").
>
> Example: $y = e^x $ is a simple exponential function.

You have managed to derive an exponential growth curve. Assuming that errors fitted are percentage in nature (like with a lognormal parent distribution), by taking say, a natural log transform (to the base e), you then have a linear regression model with normally distributed error terms.

Note, if you derive a prediction interval, upon reversing the ln values, you have a corresponding interval with center at the median (not mean) of the lognormal postulated percent error distribution (lookup properties for the parameters of the [lognormal here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)).

[EDIT] The ln linearization of your model is:

$$ln(A(t))=ln(A_{\text{initial}}) + (1/a_d)ln(2)*t$$

So, the linear regression slope estimate, say m, equals the product of ln(2) divided by $a_d$. So, $a_d$ = ln(2)/m . Similarly, a stated confidence interval for m, centered at m, can be transformed to provide a confidence interval for $a_d$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand why it is an exponential growth curve and how to check that, but I am still not sure how to estimate a_d. The areas for each time step are computed using image processing, like in the tutorial, and now I want to sum the squares of the residuals and minimize the residuals across all data points. In the tutorial, they set up a range of values for the growth rate - I did the same for the age of division - was that maybe wrong? What I expect in real life is that the age of division becomes bigger over time, as it gets more and more crowded.